# Android delete all files starting with particular word

Tags: android, delete-file

I have a problem and I hope you can help me out.

In my wallpaper app, I am saving an image to SDcard so the user can share it online via ActionBar share function.

Here is the code that does the saving:

```
 Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return bmpUri;
```

Now, I am trying to delete that image when the user leaves the activity (which means he already shared the image or decided not to share. Either way, its not needed anymore.)

I am trying to delete it with this code (Its on button click method atm, but will change that later)

```
 case R.id.btn_delete:
          //  File folder = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            File[] filenamestemp = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < filenamestemp.length; i++) {
                if (filenamestemp[i].getAbsolutePath().toString().contains("share_image_"))
                    filenamestemp[i].delete();
            }
            break;
```

The way I see it, this should work...but it doesn't.

I tried all sorts of things, but nothings works. No errors,nothing..but image is still present in Downloads directory.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the wrong directory for the written files

You are reading the files by

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

instead of:

```
File folder = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
```

These directories are not the same.

Hope it helps, if you need anything else tell me ;)

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work, so I commented it out until i think of something else. :)